# Почему выводятся не все данные ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Есть такой вопрос по ASP.NET MVC
Вот моя вьюха:

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.Class1
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Stroka1)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Stroka2)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Stroka3)

            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Stroka1)<br />
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Stroka2)<br />
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Stroka3)<br />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот метод действия:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index(string Stroka1, string Stroka2, string Stroka3)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и сама модель:

```
public class Class1
    {
        public string Stroka1 { get; set; }
        public string Stroka2 { get; set; }
        public string Stroka3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Вопрос в том, что почему при запросе такого вида:

> http://localhost:5669/home/index?Stroka1=Pavel&Stroka2=Gleb&Stroka3=Sergey

заполняются только поля представления `Html.EditorFor`, а `Html.DisplayFor` отображаются пустыми. Насколько я понимаю, при запросе такого вида создается объект модели `Class1` и соответственно должно все отображаться. Но отображается только поля ввода, но не отображения. Где я ошибаюсь, подскажите пожалуйста ? С другой стороны, в методе действия `Index` методу `View()` вообще не передается никакой модели, тогда выходит, что отображение должно быть вообще без этих данных из запроса. Но почему-то происходит все неожиданно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditorFor` задуман прежде всего для редактирования существующей модели. Онн ищет значение сначала во `ViewData.ModelState`, потом в самой модели. Это сделано для случая, когда

- вы отобразили форму
- пользоваль ввел данные - отправил из в get-строке или в теле запроса
- данные не прошли валидацию на сервере (и лежат сейчас в `ModelState`, но не в модели - потому что они могут быть совершенно не валидными для нее - например, строки которые не могут быть распаршены в целочисленные поля модели)
- вы отображаете форму как результат действия

В этом случае пользователь должен увидеть введенные им данные из `ModelState` - значения из тела запроса или из get-параметров. Поэтому `EditorFor` сначала применяет значения из `ModelState` (из запроса), а потом уже из модели. Сама модель при этом не создается - не создается экземпляр класса `Class1`.

Одно из не слишком очевидных последствий такого поведения - `EditorFor` покажет значения, переданные от клиента контроллеру даже в том случае, если в модели эти значения пустые. И даже в том случае, если во `View()` модель вы не передавали. Для явного "выбрасывания" значения из `ModelState` нужно вызвать `ModelState.Remove`:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Stroka1)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Stroka1");
    return View(); // в этом View EditorFor(m => m.Stroka1) покажет пустой текстбокс
}
```

---

`DisplayFor` задуман только для отображения данных. Для него хитрые шаги с получением в нем данных из `ModelState`, а не из модели, неаутуальны. Поэтому он просто берет значения из модели, которая у вас пустая. Заполните ее, и у вас корректно будет работать и `EditorFor` и `DisplayFor`:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Stroka1, string Stroka2, string Stroka3)
{
    return View(new Class1 { Stroka1 = Stroka1, Stroka2 = Stroka2, Stroka3 = Stroka3 } );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так вроде понятнее !! То есть дело в моем конкретном случае в особенности работы методов Эдит и Дисплей ?

Comment: @polyakov_s да. скорее - особеннось работы именно метода `EditorFor` для организации серверной валидации.

Comment: @polyakov_s Он не создает `Class1`. `EditorFor` берет имя свойства (это шаблонный метод, в который подставляется тип из директивы @model). Ищет по имени свойства значение в `ModelState`. Если нашел - показывает его в текстбоксе.

Comment: Я еще раз перечитал Ваш пост, и увидел ! Вам, огромное спасибо, а то я 2 часа своей жизни потратил, и не мог ничего понять. Теперь вошел в тему )) Спасибо !!

Answer (score -1):

Может, вам имеет смысл передавать вашей вьюхе какую-то модель? 
Насколько можно судить, здесь

```
public ActionResult Index(string Stroka1, string Stroka2, string Stroka3)
{
    return View();
}
```

у вас нет никакой модели, вы просто рендерите пустую вьюху. 
Или вы думаете, что модель волшебным образом сгенерируется сама?

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен, но по этой ссылке http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-part23-model-binding в части  первой написано, что модель и так создается. И якобы идет во вьюху. Да и к тому же вопрос меня тогда мучает, а почему тогда поля ввода заполняются данными из этой ссылки (которая в моем вопросе) ? Ведь по идее тогда все данные переданные по ссылке вообще никаким образом не должны отображаться если модель идет пустая

Comment: @polyakov_s не совсем по теме - но код по ссылке использует TempData -> использует сессию -> потенциально вызывает проблемы с производительностью. Найдите другой туториал.

Comment: Спасибо, большое, буду искать другой тогда. Я в него влез и по уши застрял