# Не передается модель enum из View в Controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, enum

Имеется модель:

```
public enum Type
{
    Phone, Tablet, Car, Other
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type? Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

ну и View:

```
@using BROCKHAUS_AG_Test_Web_App.Models
@model Product
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create product";
}

<h2>New product</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Product name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "firstField" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Type, "Product type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, "Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "firstField" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, "Price", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "firstField" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

При отправке модели в контроллер, в методе Create:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name, Description, Price")] Product product)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            product.AddDate = DateTime.Now;
            productRepository.InsertProduct(product);
            productRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

значение `product.Type` равно `null`, хотя я, вроде, его проинициализировал во Create и оправил целиком в ProductController.

Буду счастлив узнать как передать это значение в контроллер.

Comment: `[Bind(Include = "Name, Description, Price")]` - где `Type`?

Comment: из той же серии вопрос. При передаче `<td>@Html.ActionLink(product.Type.ToString(), "FilteredProducts", "Product", product.Type)</td>` в методе     `public ActionResult FilteredProducts([Bind(Include = "Type")] Models.Type? searchType)
        { ...}` параметр searchType равен null. Что не так делаю?

Comment: @Zhenia скорее у вас вот такая ситуация: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423341/ - посмотрите решение по ссылке, если поможет - я закрою ваш вопрос как дубликат

Comment: @Zhenia но вообще в вашем коде нигде Type не иницилизируется и метод CreateView не вызывается. вы точно весь код привели?

Comment: @Zhenia все равно - у вас просто нет присвоения `Type =` в Create, по крайней мере явного. если есть неявное в InsertProduct - посмотрите ответ по ссылке выше.

Comment: поменял на `[Bind(Include = "Name, Type, Description, Price")]`, работает.

Comment: @Igor подобным образом пытаюсь отправить из View `@Html.ActionLink(product.Type, "FilteredProducts", "Product", product.Type)`, но в методе `public ActionResult FilteredProducts([Bind(Include = "Type")] Models.Type? searchType) { ... }` параметр `searchType` равен `null`. Что нужно подправить?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(product.Type.ToString(), "FilteredProducts", "Product", new { searchType = product.Type })`

Comment: @Igor все равно неудача, `searchType == null` в `FilteredProducts`

Comment: @Zhenia уберите `[Bind(Include = "Type")]`